# What is the benefit of passing HTTP status with API responses?

Tags: api, design-patterns

With your error responses you need to pass some attribute that indicates the error type anyway. So that makes HTTP status code redundant or sometimes even inaccurate.

Any real benefit here, and why it shouldn't just be `200`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming we're talking about a RESTful API:

Because if you return an error message with a HTTP Status Code of 200, the client will assume his request was successful, and maybe not read the response body at all.

If the status code is 200, the client will *not* be looking for an error message in the response body.

An HTTP status code is *not* redundant. Pretty much in the same way a book's index is not redundant. First you look at the index for a topic you want to read on, and then you flip to that page and read more on that topic. Similarly, the client first reads the status code to know what happened, and then reads the response body to find out more about it.

Comment: _"...with a HTTP Status Code of 200, the client will look at the response body for the resource that was just created..."_  Shouldn't resource creation be indicated by a 201 response?